# Make jQuery code less dependent on HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with different menu items. Whenever the user clicks on a menu item, I want a description to appear below. I am doing this with jQuery and it does work. However, I'm wondering whether a better solution is available, since my solution depends heavily on the HTML structure of the document.

I have thought of giving each element an id and target it like that, but then how would I target all these different id's with one function?

here is my code so far:

```js
var greyHeadings = $('.menu-item');

function displayDescription(event) {
  $(event.target).parent().next().children().toggleClass('show-item');
}

greyHeadings.click(function() {
  displayDescription(event);
});
```

```css
table { width: 100% }

.description {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.show-item {
  display: block !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-header"><a name="boodlefight">Boodle Fight</a></th>
    <th class="table-header">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu-item">
    <td class="tablesubhead">Silogan <span class="click-for-description">click on me for a description</span></td>
    <td class="prices">135 AED</td>
    <td class="add addselected">+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="description">Beef Tapa, Longanisa, Chicken Tocino, Scrambled Egg, Daing Na Bangus, Pancit Guisado, Itlog Malat with Insaladang Talong, Garlic Rice, Dessert: Pandan Jelly or Banana Turon. All with cups of Coffee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="menu-item">
    <td class="tablesubhead">Isdaan <span class="click-for-description">click on me for a description</span></td>
    <td class="prices">195 AED</td>
    <td class="add addselected">+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="description">Beef Tapa, Longanisa, Chicken Tocino, Scrambled Egg, Daing Na Bangus, Pancit Guisado, Itlog Malat with Insaladang Talong, Garlic Rice, Dessert: Pandan Jelly or Banana Turon. All with cups of Coffee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(or as [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nb34w70/))

My worry is with this line:

```
$(event.target).parent().next().children().toggleClass('show-item');
```

Should I ever change my HTML, this might not work anymore.

Comment: i dont see an id in the sample code. all i see are classes

Comment: Yes you  can add dynamic id or index for each iteration. then target that certain element using jquery `$(this)` . hehe pinoy inside :)

Comment: Maybe do a container div and take the child of it can be a solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as you've noted: your current solution relies on the document having a given structure. If you decide to rearrange the HTML, the JS would need to change as well, and you want to avoid that.

A possible solution would be to relate the HTML elements one to another, like so:

```
<a href="/my/menu/item" class="menu-item" rel="menuitem-1">Clicky</a>
<!-- some HTML -->
<div id="menuitem-1">Description</div>
```

This way, whenever the menu item is clicked, you can programmatically select the related tag and do whatever you need:

```
var greyHeadings = $('.menu-item');

function displayDescription(id) {
    $(id).toggleClass('show-item');
}

greyHeadings.click(function() {
    displayDescription($(this).attr("rel"));
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks really good! However, I read that I need the `<a>` tag in order to use the `rel`. How could I implement this with my table?

Comment: I figured it out, it seems to work with tr's too :). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by generating the HTML so that you will have something like this

```
  <tr class="menu-item" data-index="5">
    <td class="tablesubhead">Silogan <span class="click-for-description">click on me for a description</span></td>
    <td class="prices">135 AED</td>
    <td class="add addselected">+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-index="5">
    <td class="description">Beef Tapa, Longanisa, Chicken Tocino, Scrambled Egg, Daing Na Bangus, Pancit Guisado, Itlog Malat with Insaladang Talong, Garlic Rice, Dessert: Pandan Jelly or Banana Turon. All with cups of Coffee</td>
  </tr>
```

And then you can do this with Javascript:

```
var greyHeadings = $('.menu-item');

function displayDescription(event) {
  $("[data-index=" + $(event.target).data("index") + "]").toggleClass('show-item');
}

greyHeadings.click(function() {
  displayDescription(event);
});
```

The downside of this solution is that you always search for the items in the whole DOM. You can cache items which were already searched for if needed to speed up the process:

```
var indexCache = {};
var greyHeadings = $('.menu-item');

function displayDescription(event) {
  var index = $(event.target).data("index");
  if (!indexCache[index]) {
      indexCache[index] = $("[data-index=" + index + "]");
  }
  indexCache[index].toggleClass('show-item');
}

greyHeadings.click(function() {
  displayDescription(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use closest()

https://api.jquery.com/closest/ ... you will have this code

```
$(this).closest('.menu-item').next().toggleClass('show-item');
```